# How to return only some columns of a relations with Typeorm

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Ok, i'm having trouble with getting the relations with typeorm, when i run the service it returns me all the data from the relation, and i want only specific fields, like id and name.

Here's my code:

```
async findById(id: string): Promise<UsersUseOfferHistoric> {
return await this.repository.findOne({
  where: { id },
  relations: ['userId', 'offerId'],
  });
}
```

Here's the json Output:

```
{
"id": "da0fd04e-17c6-4412-b342-a4361d191468",
"createdAt": "2020-01-07T19:48:30.840Z",
"userId": {
    "id": "bdc00227-569f-44b5-9bdd-c8de03661ebd",
    "name": "Alexandre Vieira",
    "cpf": "10443771430",
    "email": "av.souza2018@gmail.com",
    "password": "asjdsifjdsfasf",
    "imagePath": "/me.png",
    "active": true,
    "lastLogin": "2020-01-07T19:40:26.850Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-01-07T19:40:26.850Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-07T19:40:26.850Z"
},
"offerId": {
    "id": "e399560c-d2c2-4f4e-b2b1-94cae3af3779",
    "offerDrescription": "Nova oferta top",
    "discountCoupon": " Desconto top",
    "discountValidity": "2020-01-07T14:18:19.803Z",
    "discountPercentage": 20,
    "discountQuantityLimit": 50,
    "createdAt": "2020-01-07T19:45:33.589Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-07T19:45:33.589Z"
   }
}
```

Here's the output i want:

```
{
"id": "da0fd04e-17c6-4412-b342-a4361d191468",
"createdAt": "2020-01-07T19:48:30.840Z",
"userId": {
    "id": "bdc00227-569f-44b5-9bdd-c8de03661ebd",
    "name": "Alexandre Vieira",

},
"offerId": {
    "id": "e399560c-d2c2-4f4e-b2b1-94cae3af3779",
    "offerDrescription": "Nova oferta top",

   }
}
```

Comment: got any solution for this ? don't want to. use createQueryBuilder()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `findOne` function accepts an `select: ['id', 'createdAt']` property where you can filter the fields of the outgoing relation. To explicitly select the returned fields of a joined table (using the `relations` property does implicitly a left join) you have to use a [query builder](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder).

```ts
await getRepository(Foo).createQueryBuilder('foo')
  .where({ id: 1})
  .select(['foo.id', 'foo.createdAt', 'bar.id', 'bar.name'])
  .leftJoin('foo.bars', 'bar')  // bar is the joined table
  .getMany();
```

Comment: What is `foo`??

Comment: `foo` is an alias for `Foo` table

Answer (score 20):

You can do it like this if you rather use the repository API instead of the queryBuilder

```js
return await this.repository.findOne({
  where: { id },
  select: {
    userId: {
      id: true,
      name: true
    },
    offerId: {
      id: true,
      offerDrescription: true
    }
  },
  relations: {
    userId: true,
    offerId: true,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Try something like that:

```
...findOne({
    select: {
        id: true,
        createdAt: true,
        userId: {
          id: true,
          name: true,
        },
        offerId: {
          id: true,
          offerDrescription: true,
        },
      },
      ...
      where: {...},
})
```

Comment: It works from version **0.3.0**

Comment: This does not seem to work for many-to-one relations? (e.g. `select: { offers: { id: true } }`)