# How to Select Some Fields From Relations in Typeorm Relations

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I need to Select Some fields from relations in Nest.js TypeOrm .
For Example My Entity is :

```
 @Entity()
 export class Chat {
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
 public id: number;

 @Column()
 public orderId: number;

 @Column({ default: ChatStatus.Active })
 public status: ChatStatus;

 @Column()
 public userId: number;

 @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.chats, { nullable: true })
 @JoinColumn({ name: 'userId' })
 public user: User;
}
```

**Any In My Service :**

```
async findAll(dataSearch) {
  return await this.chatRepository.find({
    relations: ['user'],
  });
}
```

I Want Just Select **"name"** , **"avatar"** from user relation but This select all Columns.

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645009/how-to-return-only-some-columns-of-a-relations-with-typeorm

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column({ type: "timestamp", default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP',
```

> select: false

})
updated_at: Timestamp;

Example

```
@Column({ type: "timestamp", default: () => 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', select: false })
```